# how to disable Angular required field msg?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to disable this message "Please fill out this field.":

[image]

I would like to use my own custom message; I'm suspecting this comes from Angular, but can't seem to disable it.  I thought about disabling it through css, but don't know the class or id.  I tried to do 'inspect element', but this message goes away when I try.

Here is the html form if it helps.

```
<form name="personalForm" role="form" ng-submit="updatePersonal(updatePersonalForm)"
          ng-init="updatePersonalForm = {first_name: userFirstName,
            last_name: userLastName, job_title: userJobTitle, company_name: userCompanyName,
            location: userLocation, website: userWebsite}">

            <div class="auth-body">
              <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>first name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name"
                    required class="form-control" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.first_name"
                    ng-class="{ 'error-input': personalForm.first_name.$invalid}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name"
                    required class="form-control" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.last_name"
                    ng-class="{ 'error-input': personalForm.last_name.$invalid}">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>job title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="job_title" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.job_title"
                     class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>location</label>
                    <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.location"
                     class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>company name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company_name" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.company_name"
                     class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="form-group personal-form-group">
                    <label>personal website</label>
                    <input type="text" name="personal_website" ng-model="updatePersonalForm.website"
                     class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
                  <button type="submit" class="bubble-btn submit-btn pull-left" style="float: none !important;">update</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

I was able to print out these options, but can't seem to find the option for that required msg, maybe it's not even there.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my below answer?

Comment: @Aruna just did, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above validation is fired by `HTML5` and not by `AngularJS`. You can turn this off by adding the `novalidate` attribute in your`form` as below,

```
<form novalidate name="personalForm" role="form" ng-submit="updatePersonal(updatePersonalForm)"
          ng-init="updatePersonalForm = {first_name: userFirstName,
            last_name: userLastName, job_title: userJobTitle, company_name: userCompanyName,
            location: userLocation, website: userWebsite}">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add novalidate to your form tag. This will prevent default HTML5 validation.

```
 <form action=" " novalidate>
     //form body
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this behavior for all fields inside the form do this:

```
<form name="formName" novalidate>
    <!-- all fields... -->
</form>
```

... or... if you want to set that behavior just for specific fields, do the same to those fields. When you set the attribute for a specific field, it overrides the parent form behavior

```
<form name="formName">
    <label> Enter your text here </label>
    <input type="text" formnovalidate />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable it for a specific field just take off the `required` or `ng-required` directive.